# NvAPI_GPU_GetAllDisplayIds function not working as expected

Tags: c++, malloc, nvapi

I'm using [NVAPI](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/coresdk/nvapi/index.html) in C++ to modify NVIDIA display settings in my program.

I cannot successfully use the `NvAPI_GPU_GetAllDisplayIds` function. The status returned from calling it is `NVAPI_INCOMPATIBLE_STRUCT_VERSION`.

Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    NvAPI_Status status;

    NvPhysicalGpuHandle nvGPUHandle[64];
    NvU32 gpuCount;
    status = NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs(nvGPUHandle, &gpuCount);
    if (NVAPI_OK != status) {
        cerr << "Failed to run function: NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs\nStatus: " << status << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (gpuCount <= 0) {
        cerr << "No GPU's found" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < gpuCount; ++i) {
        const NvPhysicalGpuHandle& hPhysicalGpu = nvGPUHandle[i];

        NvU32 displayIdCount = 0;
        status = NvAPI_GPU_GetAllDisplayIds(hPhysicalGpu, nullptr, &displayIdCount);
        if (NVAPI_OK != status) {
            cerr << "Failed to run function: NvAPI_GPU_GetAllDisplayIds\nStatus: " << status << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        if (displayIdCount <= 0) {
            cerr << "No display's found" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        NV_GPU_DISPLAYIDS* displayIds = static_cast<NV_GPU_DISPLAYIDS*>(malloc(sizeof(NV_GPU_DISPLAYIDS) * displayIdCount));
        status = NvAPI_GPU_GetAllDisplayIds(hPhysicalGpu, displayIds, &displayIdCount);
        if (NVAPI_OK != status) {
            // status is NVAPI_INCOMPATIBLE_STRUCT_VERSION (-9)
            cerr << "Failed to run function: NvAPI_GPU_GetAllDisplayIds\nStatus: " << status << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Am I using `malloc` incorrectly or something?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not documented directly in the NVAPI documentation page for that function, but you need to set the version on your malloc'ed `displayIds` structure before passing it in to `NvAPI_GPU_GetAllDisplayIds`. Add this line before the call:

```
displayIds->version = NV_GPU_DISPLAYIDS_VER;
```

This seems to be pretty standard throughout the NVAPI with other function calls as well.

Comment: Is what I'm attempting possible? I've searched the source code of NvAPI for words like `contrast`, `gamma`, `brightness` and have found no functions with the ability to change these simple settings. Maybe I'm confused as to what NvAPI actually is meant to do.

Comment: Best Google result I found for this is https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/543255/nvapi-set-brightness-contrast-hue-saturation/ . Apparently it might be available in the (paid) version of the NVAPI.

Comment: You should be canonised man :D On the other hand the guy who wrote the docs...